# How to use an object and function as predicate for angular filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to filter an ng-repeated list by an object and a function as well.

For eg:

I need to do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="fruit in fruitBasket | filter: { name: 'orange', shape: 'round' }: quantityExists()>
```

So above the quantity exists checks to see whether the quantity required is less than the quantity available. Note I also want to filter by the object specified.

Sorry if this example doesnt make complete sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="fruit in fruitBasket | filter: { name: 'orange', shape: 'round' }|filter: quantityExists">
```

Now, write a `filter` called `quantityExists` or if you use like `filter: quantityExists()`, make sure that this function should return a value or object

Comment: I returned a boolean value from the quantityExists function and it worked.